# NSDate nil after returning from method

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a simple method that determines the NSDate from a string like "NOV 2017". When I step through the method, actualDate has the correct value but nil is passed to the calling method.

The code below was working until recently, I'm on Xcode 9.0 targeting iOS 10 / 11.

Here is the calling method

```
NSDate *eventDate = [DateClass dateFromMonthYearString:@"NOV 2017"];
```

Method definition

```
+(NSDate*)dateFromMonthYearString:(NSString*)monthYearString
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [self cachedFormatter];
    [formatter setDateFormat:MONTH_YEAR_DATE_FORMAT];

    NSDate* actualDate = [formatter dateFromString:monthYearString];
    return actualDate;
}

+(NSDateFormatter*) cachedFormatter
{
    if (cachedDateFormatter == nil)
    {
        cachedDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        cachedDateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentAppLocale];
    }

    return cachedDateFormatter;
}
```

The MONTH_YEAR_DATE_FORMAT is defined as ...

```
NSString * const MONTH_YEAR_DATE_FORMAT = @"MMM yyyy";
```

When I print the date object inside the method definition, Xcode prints the date correctly. When I try to 'po' outside the method definition, I just get something like this

```
(lldb) po eventDate
0x000000012eb048e0
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you show us `MONTH_YEAR_DATE_FORMAT`? Also, if your format is always `MMM yyyy`, you should probably use `dateFormat` string, not localizing it.

Comment: As an aside, there’s no benefit to caching a formatter if you’re going to copy it and reset the format every time. It’s the setting of the format that’s expensive, not the instantiation of the formatter, itself (esp if you’re going to copy it).

Answer (score 0):

So when I print the values to the console via NSLog, it prints the correct value. Looks like its just the variable display and 'po' commands don't work correctly in X9.1 Weird ??